# how to forward back to JSP page without losing the data entered in fields?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp

I have a simple MVC-based JSP application.  Something like:

`*.jsp -> ControllerServlet -> *Command.java -> *Service.java -> *DAO.java -> Oracle db`

A typical link in the application looks like this:

`myapp/controller?cmd=ShowEditUser&userid=55`

Which causes `ShowEditUserCommand.java` execute() method to run and will forward to `editUser.jsp`

In `editUser.jsp`, they fill in the fields, then click `Save` which posts to `myapp/controller?cmd=ModifyUser` which runs `ModifyUserCommand.java` execute() method which modifies the user data and forwards to `viewUser.jsp`.

Everything works fine.

The problem is, in `ModifyUserCommand.execute()` I'm checking to see if the username is unique.  If they try to enter a username that already exists, I set an error value to `true` and errorMessage value to `Already in use`.

Then because of the error I forward to the original `editUser.jsp` (not viewUser.jsp) and the error is displayed above the form.

MY PROBLEM IS (finally! ;) -- when the user is returned to `editUser.jsp` with the error message displayed, the data they entered in the fields is all blanked out.  How can I set it so whatever they entered in the fields is still in place?

Any suggestions or advice are greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to pass the form fields back to your editUser.jsp in your forward action in ModifyUserCommand.execute().  You can do that with individual parameters i.e.

```
editUser.jsp?field1=1&field2=2
```

Alternatively, you could pass data with other methods - i.e. encoded JSON.

You can then process your fields in your editUser.jsp via the page's request object and set your form field values accordingly.

There may be other ways to do this depending on what underlying framework (if any) you are using.  But this is a basic way of approaching it.

Comment: My last big project was JSF and it handled this sort of thing for me.  This project is home-grown JSPs so I didn't realize how good I had it with JSFs! :) Thanks for the suggestion.